# React Form values are not reflected on the FORM items for EDIT using class state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forms

I'm pulling data from MongoDB and trying to edit the data but for some reason, my form is not showing the values on the form. Can anyone help to guide me on what I am getting wrong? below is my code for any help why **form value** are not updated using `this.state.job_title` as an example:

**edit-job.component.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default class EditJob extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangeJob_title = this.onChangeJob_title.bind(this);
    this.onChangejob_comp_image = this.onChangejob_comp_image.bind(this);
    this.onChangejob_comp_name = this.onChangejob_comp_name.bind(this);
    this.onChangejob_description = this.onChangejob_description.bind(this);
    this.onChangejob_location = this.onChangejob_location.bind(this);
    this.onChangejob_field = this.onChangejob_field.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDatejob_closing_date =
      this.onChangeDatejob_closing_date.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      job_title: "",
      job_comp_image: "",
      job_comp_name: "",
      job_description: "",
      job_location: "",
      job_field: "",
      job_closing_date: new Date(),
      users: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //GET CURRENT JOB LISTING TO EDIT
    if (this.props.match && this.props.match.params.id) {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:5001/jobs/" + this.props.match.params.id)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.setState({
            username: response.data.username,
            job_title: response.data.job_title,
            job_comp_image: response.data.job_comp_image,
            job_comp_name: response.data.job_comp_name,
            job_description: response.data.job_description,
            job_location: response.data.job_location,
            job_field: response.data.job_field,
            job_closing_date: new Date(response.data.job_closing_date),
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5001/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({
            users: response.data.map((user) => user.username),
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  //Update user with new username entered by user
  onChangeJob_title(e) {
    this.setState({
      job_title: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangejob_comp_image(e) {
    this.setState({
      job_comp_image: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangejob_comp_name(e) {
    this.setState({
      job_comp_name: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangejob_description(e) {
    this.setState({
      job_description: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangejob_location(e) {
    this.setState({
      job_location: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangejob_field(e) {
    this.setState({
      job_field: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangeDatejob_closing_date(job_closing_date) {
    this.setState({
      job_closing_date: job_closing_date,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const job = {
      username: this.state.username,
      job_title: this.state.username,
      job_comp_image: this.state.job_comp_image,
      job_comp_name: this.state.job_comp_name,
      job_description: this.state.job_description,
      job_location: this.state.job_location,
      job_field: this.state.job_field,
      job_closing_date: new Date(),
    };

    console.log(job);

    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:5001/jobs/update/" + this.props.match.params.id,
        job
      )
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    window.location = "/";
  }

  render() {
    const Headerstyle = {
      marginTop: "40px",
    };
    return (
      <div style={Headerstyle}>
        <h3>Edit Exercise Log</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Username: </label>
            <select
              UseRef="userInput"
              required
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
            >
              {this.state.users.map(function (user) {
                return (
                  <option key={user} value={user}>
                    {user}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Job Title: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              required
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.job_title}
              onChange={this.onChangeJob_title}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Company Image: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.job_comp_image}
              onChange={this.onChangejob_comp_image}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Company Name: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.job_comp_name}
              onChange={this.onChangejob_comp_name}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Job Description: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.job_description}
              onChange={this.onChangejob_description}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Job Location: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.job_location}
              onChange={this.onChangejob_location}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Job related field: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.job_field}
              onChange={this.onChangejob_field}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Job Closing Date: </label>
            <div>
              <DatePicker
                selected={this.state.job_closing_date}
                onChange={this.onChangeDatejob_closing_date}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Edit Job Listing"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you're tring for bounded form right? are you getting any of the initial values

Comment: do you mean the value from the database ?